# Can I use it "es ist verwendet Brot essen."

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

**"es ist gewohnt Brot essen."** means "It is used to eat bread" right?

The Google Translate translates it to **"Es wird verwendet, um Brot zu essen"**. 
which sentence is right or is more common?

Comment: Oh my. Google translate is not a good source for example translations. Hint: The English phrase „used to“ has two quite different meanings, one indicating a habit, the other a tool. The corresponding German phrases are completely unrelated.

Comment: @Stephie Though you are right that Google is not a good source, your comment confuses more than it helps. This is so, because here Google's translation is obviously correct, whereas the OP's own translation is not.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Agreed. This might be because the original English might not necessarily be what the OP intended to say.

Comment: Could you please write in English, what you actually want to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "es ist gewohnt Brot essen." means "It is used to eat bread" right?

No. Both sentences are wrong.

The correct translation of the apparently intended meaning would be

> Es ist es gewohnt, Brot zu essen.
>   It is used to eating bread.

(In this case, *it* could be for example *the child.*)

The other translation, which might sound similar in English, has a different meaning:

> Es wird verwendet, um Brot zu essen.
>   It is used to eat bread.

(In this case, *it* could be for example *a knife.*)

Remarkably, both translations are correct in Google Translate.

Comment: If this sentence is in a school questionnaire where the parents have mark with a cross: yes or no, then

"es ist gewohnt Brot essen"

 will mean: 

it is used to eating bread.

Answer (score 2):

*"It is used to eat bread"* can have two distinct meanings, in English:

1. *It is utilised with the purpose of eating bread* — *it* is a tool of some sort
2. *It has the habit of eating bread* — *it* is a person (child) or animal

Note that 2. is probably better written as *"It is used to **eating** bread"* (which is not the same as *"It used to eat bread"*, which means it usually ate bread).

The translations are different too:

1. *Es wird verwendet, um Brot zu essen*
2. *Es ist es gewohnt, Brot zu essen*